# Why can't I connect to MySQL via Shell/Workbench when Wampserver is running?

Tags: mysql, wamp

I'm very new at this, and have just learned SQL. I've set up MySQL Workbench, Shell, and Server on my Windows 10 PC, I've made a database, and I've used it just fine. My plan is to learn a few other languages (Python's next) and make a website using this database.

The next thing I did is install Wampserver, which I gather I'll need as I get further along with making my website. Once I had Wampserver running, I couldn't connect to MySQL via Shell/Workbench. I had to stop Wampserver's MySQL service; this allowed me to connect in MySQL Shell and access my database, which is great-- but I'm not clear on why Wampserver's MySQL service stood in the way, or whether or not that'll be a problem down the line.

Not sure how to handle this, or even whether or not it needs handling!

What I thought would happen is that I'd download and install Wampserver, and then I'd move my database from its original location on the MySQL server to the new local server I had set up via Wampserver. (In case this isn't clear: I'm still fumbling my way a little bit around what all of this means.) I had found instructions online and thought I'd follow them.

Instead, after I installed Wampserver, I couldn't access my database, and soon realized I couldn't connect in MySQL Shell/Workbench as I had previously.

Comment: Wampserver won't help you if you want to develop in Python; it's a PHP based stack. Your issue is that Wampserver installs and runs its own MySQL DB server

Comment: In that case, I guess my next question is what I should be using instead of Wampserver!

But also, in case I want to work with PHP at a later date: what would've been the way to handle this? To export the database from its current location, put it on Wampserver's MySQL server, and use that instead? (Would I still be able to use Workbench with that?)

Comment: That's really subjective and off-topic for Stack Overflow. As far as I know for Python, you don't need any particular server setup like WAMP (which stands for Windows + Apache + MySQL + PHP). Since you already have MySQL up and running you should only need Python after that.

Comment: You don't actually need all that for PHP either. It has its own [built-in web development server](https://www.php.net/manual/features.commandline.webserver.php).

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate issue is that you now have 3 database servers running, 2 of which will be trying to use the same port number, 3306. The MySQL that you installed when you installed WorkBench and now MySQL and mariaDB that came with WAMPServer.

It is quite possible to run multiple MySQL/mariaDB servers, but does need some careful feteling to make them all work and get apps to use the right one, a little to much for now I think.

I would have expected the Original MySQL to have been set to "Start at Boot", this is what normally happens when you install MySQL with Workbench. But from what you say, its probable you modified that so you have to manually start the original MySQL.

So if you start WAMPServer first, it will start it's MySQL and probably mariaDB services. This of course will be a different instance of MySQL and will look like your databases have dissapeared. What is happening is, WAMPServer-MySQL will have grabbed port 3306 and when you start the original-MySQL it wont be able to use port 3306 so will not start until you stop WAMPServer.

In reality, it would be best, if you are going to stick with WAMPServer to remove the original MySQL that was installed with Workbench, Workbench will still work with the WAMPServer MySQL. But before doing this, take a backup of the database's you created, save the backup safely in another folder completely, so you can restore them to the WAMPServer version of MySQL. Then uninstall the original MySQL.

Once uninstalled, start WAMPServer and restore the databases to WAMPServer's MySQL. You will now be seeing MySQL and your database(s) in the single instance on MySQL which is part of WAMPServer.

Also as Phil says, WAMPServer does not come out of the box with Python, but it is quite possible to install Python and configure it into your WAMPServer.

Another option would be to look at XAMPP, which does come with Python pre-installed but is not so flexible when it comes to installing various versions of PHP/MySQL/mariaDB/phpMyAdmin. The process of moving your databases would be the same for this option.